# Why solutions of $y''+(w^2+b(t))y=0$ behave like solutions of $y''+w^2y=0$ at infinity

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Assume $w>0$ and $b(t)$ be continuous on $[0,+\infty)$ and $\int_0^\infty |b(t)| dt <\infty$
show that $y''+(w^2+b(t))y=0$ has solution $\phi(t)$ such that $$\lim_{t\to\infty} [(\phi(t)-\sin(wt))^2+(\phi'(t)-w\cos(wt))^2]=0$$

thanks

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\lim_{t\to \infty}$?

Comment: @Raskolnikov: yes

Comment: What are the initial conditions for $\phi(t)$?

Comment: @Raskolinkov : it is not important.

Comment: The reason why this happens is easy to understand. Since the integral exists and $b(t)$ is continuous we have $\lim_{t\to\infty}b(t) = 0$ so the equation reads $y'' + w^2 y \approx 0$ for large $t$. To prove it requires some more work.

Comment: @winther: exactly,  I need proof

Comment: I am curious. Which book do you get this problem from?

Comment: Lecture notes of our professor. I have found solution in general case in coddingtone and levinson.  But i was curious to see other simple way.

Comment: Could you please refer me to the relevant page of Coddington and Levinson? Is it in Chapter 13? Thanks.

Comment: Problems 29 and 30 of chapter 3 page 104 and 105 coddington and levinson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another proof (apologies for any similarities, but I think it's different enough). Put $Y = y + i\dot y/w$ and write $\beta(t) = b(t)/w$. Then with initial conditions $Y(0) = Y_0$ the differential equation can be written
\begin{align*}
 \dot Y = -iwY - i\beta y,\qquad Y(0) = Y_0. \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Since
\begin{align*}
 {d\over dt}(Ye^{iwt}) &= (\dot Y + iw Y)e^{iwt} = -i\beta y e^{iwt},
\end{align*}
we can write
\begin{align*}
 Y(t)e^{iwt} - Y(s)e^{iws} &= -i\int_{s}^t \beta(r)y(r)e^{iwr}\,dr.
\end{align*}

Set $B = \int_0^\infty |\beta(r)|\,dr$. In a moment I will prove that
\begin{align*}
 |Y(t)|\leq e^B|Y(s)|, \qquad s,t\geq0. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Suppose for now that this is proved. Then for any time $t_0$,
\begin{align*}
 |Y(t)e^{iwt} - Y(s)e^{iws}| \leq e^B|Y(t_0)| \int_s^t|\beta(r)|\,dr, \tag{3}
\end{align*}
which since the right side tends to $0$ as $s,t\to\infty$ implies that $Y(t)e^{iwt}$ has a limit $Y(\infty)$ as $t\to\infty$. If $z$ is an arbitrary point in the plane, I claim that we can make $Y(\infty) = z$. (This is enough to answer the question because $Y(t)$ converges to the curve $Y(\infty)e^{-iwt}$.) To prove the claim, define a map $\Lambda\colon\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ by setting $\Lambda(\zeta) = Y_\zeta(\infty)$, where $Y_\zeta$ is the solution to the ODE $(1)$ with initial condition $Y_\zeta(0) = \zeta$. Observe that $\Lambda$ is a linear map (using $Y_\zeta(t) + cY_\xi(t) = Y_{\zeta + c\xi}(t)$, which is because the left side is a solution to $(1)$ passing through $\zeta + c\xi$ at time zero and because there is only one such solution), and that the inequality $(2)$ implies that $\Lambda$ is invertible: $e^{-B}|\zeta|\leq |\Lambda(\zeta)|$. An invertible linear map on the plane is surjective, so the claim is proved.

It remains to prove $(2)$. For this I'll use Gronwall's inequality twice. Gronwall's inequality says that if $u(t)$ is real-valued and satisfies $\dot u(t)\leq f(t)u(t)$ for $a\leq t\leq b$, then $u(t) \leq e^{\int_a^tf(s)\,ds}u(a)$ for $t\in [a,b]$. The proof involves writing $$u(t) = e^{\int_a^tf(s)\,ds}u(a) + e^{\int_a^tf(s)\,ds}\int_a^t(\dot u(s) - f(s)u(s))e^{-\int_a^sf(r)\,dr}\,ds$$
and observing that the integral is negative for $t\in[a,b]$.

On now to the proof of $(2)$. Fix $s$. I'll first use Gronwall's inequality to show that $|Y(t)|\leq e^B|Y(s)|$ for $t\geq s$. From what we showed above,
\begin{align*}
 \left|{d\over dt} (Ye^{iwt})\right| = |-i\beta ye^{iwt}| \leq |\beta||Y|.
\end{align*}
Thus
\begin{align*}
 {d\over dt}|Y| &= {d\over dt}|Ye^{iwt}| = \operatorname{Re}\left({\bar{Y}e^{-iwt}\over |Y|}{d\over dt} (Ye^{iwt})\right)\leq \left|{d\over dt} (Ye^{iwt})\right|\leq |\beta||Y|,
\end{align*}
and applying Gronwall's inequality on the half-line $t\geq s$ gives the desired bound. All that's left is to show that $|Y(t)|\leq e^B|Y(s)|$ for $t\leq s$. To do this put $U(t) = Y(s-t)$ for $t\in[0,s]$, so that $U$ satisfies the reverse time equation
\begin{align*}
 \dot U(t) = iwU(t) + i\beta(s-t)\operatorname{Re}U(t)
\end{align*}
Thus differentiating $Ue^{-iwt}$ and running the same proof as before gives ${d\over dt}|U|\leq |\beta(s-t)||U|$, and then Gronwall's inequality gives $|Y(s - t)|\leq e^B |Y(s)|$ for $t\in[0,s]$, which is equivalent to $Y(t)\leq e^BY(s)$ for $0\leq t\leq s$. With that, $(2)$ is proved.

Comment: I changed the approach a little bit. Hopefully it's simpler now, and it should be free of egregious errors. (But doesn't the author always think that at the time of posting?) It's likely not free of verbosity—I certainly wish it were more concise—but I do what I can.

Comment: I like your approach very much! I was thinking about the mapping between the initial values at 0 and at ∞. You lay it out beautifully. I suppose this method generalizes to the linear matrix ODE $\dot y=(A(t)+B(t))y$ where $\int_0^\infty |B|<\infty$.

Comment: Thanks very much, @Hans. I struggled a bit myself with how best to formulate the mapping between initial values at $0$ and $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an outline of an approach that almost gets there (with some pieces left to be filled in). I will show that we can find solutions $\phi(t)$ that are arbitrarily close to $\sin wt$ for all sufficiently large $t$ under the assumption that $\lim_{t\to\infty}b(t) = 0$.

Write the solution to the ODE as $\phi(t) = \sin w t + \delta y$ and impose the initial conditions $\delta y(t_*) = \delta y'(t_*) = 0$ for some $t_*$ to be fixed later on. Then

$$\delta y'' + (w^2+b)\delta y = -b\sin w t$$

This system is equivalent to a ball rolling without friction attached to a spring with varying spring-constant and we have some driving force $b(t)\sin wt$.

This physics-analogy motivates us to try to find an 'energy equation' for this system. Multiply by $\delta y'$ to find

$$\frac{d}{dt}(\delta y'^2 + w^2\delta y^2) = -b(t)\left(2\sin w t\frac{d\delta y}{dt} + \frac{d\delta y^2}{dt}\right)$$

Integrating over $[t_*,t]$ yields

$$(\delta y'^2 + w^2\delta y^2) \leq \max_{t'\in [t_*,t]}|b(t')|\left(2|\delta y| + \delta y^2\right)$$

Now since $y$ is bounded (I will just assume this here, see the other answer for the proof. Physically this is because the energy is bounded.) and $b\to 0$ (Edit: $b\to 0$ does not follow from continuity, but I will need to assume this here) we get that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exist a $t_*$ s.t. for $t>t_*$ we have

$$\delta y'^2 + w^2\delta y^2 < \epsilon$$

and since $w$ is a constant it also follows that we can find a $t_*$ s.t.

$$\delta y'^2 + \delta y^2 < \epsilon$$

for all $t>t_*$. Writing out this equation we get

$$(\phi(t)-\sin wt)^2 + (\phi'(t)-w\cos wt)^2 < \epsilon$$

for $t>t_*$. Thus there exists solutions that are arbitrarely close to $y=\sin w t$ for all sufficiently large $t$, however I have not yet found a way to show that we can find *one particular* solution where the difference goes to zero at infinity.

Comment: Ingenious idea. However, there are a few issues need to be addressed. 1) $b$ needs not vanish at $\infty$ since the $|b|$ may be integrable on the positive axis without having even a limit at $\infty$. 2) The bounded energy rationale does not exactly stand because the right hand side of the energy equation is a source, and one does not know how much energy is pumped into the system.

Comment: @Hans 1) Yes you are right, I guess I assumed $b$ to be in $L^2$ here. 2) No, one does need to show that $y$ is bounded to prove this (and perhaps one needs to add some conditions on $b$). This seems very plausible though if $b$ is bounded and has a finite integral. To prove this seems harder... I'm not even convinced myself that this method can give the desired result - it seems like there should be a better way to show this, but I'm still thinking about it.

Comment: 2) I am not saying you should not show $\delta y$ is bounded. I am saying your physical rationale is not reason enough to conclude that. However, you may use Gronwall's inequality as in abel's answer to prove the boundedness of $\delta y$.

Comment: @mba: I am curious why you accepted this answer. Even Winther himself acknowledged his answer was wrong.

Comment: @Hans Where did I acknowledged that my answer was *wrong*? I totally agree that the argument can be done better and that I think that there is a better solution here, and also that I don't fully reach the desired result, but saying *wrong* is a bit strong don't you think?

Comment: Do you acknowledge it is wrong to conclude $b\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$ which is needed for your proof? Do you acknowledge that you have NOT proved the boundedness of $y$ which is needed for your proof? Is flawed proof not wrong? Besides the first conclusion is WRONG not just incomplete, do you not agree? Is a proof full of holes not wrong? If not, then anyone can write a proof for Poincare conjecture.

Comment: @Hans I agree that I do assume that $b$ is well behaved (which I should have added to the text and will now). With regard to boundedness I do state that I assume this result (and as you point out this is proven by the other answer here). I'm not trying to claim anything more than I can. I agree on this answer having flaws and is not perfect, but I would not use the word wrong (and yes there is a difference).

Comment: I really like your idea, which I have stated. I know the word "wrong" does sound harsh. But I think we need to be honest with ourselves. Do you agree or not it is wrong to conclude $b$ vanishes at infinity? Yes or no? I understand you have added this statement as a new condition. But you are solving a different problem albeit related than the one that is asking. Also, it would be better if you write out the derivation for boundedness. If "wrong" is not the right word, what word would you use? At least, do you think this answer, which does not answer the original question, should be accepted?

Comment: Alright, if "wrong" is an overly harsh word, let's use "flawed". But I still do not think it should be accepted as the RIGHT answer, unless the original poser changes his question.

Comment: @Hans Good, and I agree with that, this answer does not solve the problem as it's stated.

Comment: @Hans I don't get why it's wrong to assume that $b (t) \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow +\infty$ because for me it's a necessary condition for an integral to converge.

Comment: @Evgeny Take the function $f(x) = 2^n$ for $x \in [2^n,2^n + 4^{-n}]$ (for all integer $n$) and zero otherwise (this is not continuous, but it is easy to smooth it to make it so). Then $\int f(x) dx = \sum 2^{n} \times 4^{-n} = \sum 2^{-n} = 1 < \infty$, but the function has arbitrarely large values as $x\to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

The following proof does not originate from me but the hint in Coddington and Levinson's ODE book. I write it out in full here for my own and perhaps others' benefit.

---

Let $y_0(t)=\sin(\omega t)$, and
$$y_{i+1}(t) = \sin(\omega t)+\frac{1}{\omega}\Big(\cos(\omega t)\int_t^\infty \sin( \omega s) b(s) y_i(s) ds- \sin(\omega t) \int_t^\infty \cos(\omega s) b(s) y_i(s) ds\Big).$$

For large $T$ such that 
$$\int_T^\infty |b|<\frac{1}{2},$$
we have $|y_1(t)|<\infty$ and a uniform Cauchy sequence $y_i(t)$ where 
\begin{align*}
&\big|y_{i+1}(t)-y_i(t)\big| \\
=& \frac{1}{\omega}\Big(\cos(\omega t)\int_t^\infty \sin( \omega s) b(s) (y_i(s)-y_{i-1}(s)) ds- \sin(\omega t)\int_t^\infty \cos(\omega s) b(s)(y_i(s)-y_{i-1}(s))ds\Big) \\
<& \frac{K}{2^i}
\end{align*}
for some positive constant $K$ and $\forall t \ge T$. So $y_i(t)$ approaches to a function $y_\infty$ uniformly where $|y_\infty|<K$ and
$$y_\infty(t) = \sin(\omega t)+\frac{1}{\omega}\Big(\cos(\omega t)\int_t^\infty \sin( \omega s) b(s) y_\infty(s) ds- \sin(\omega t) \int_t^\infty \cos(\omega s) b(s) y_\infty(s) ds\Big).$$

(I will finish the proof later.)

Answer (score -1):

i think you need integral representation of the solution $y$ and an application of the gronwall's inequality.

rewrite the $y^{''} + \omega^2 y = -by$ a particular solution is $$y(t) = {1 \over \omega} \cos (\omega t)\int_0^t \sin( \omega s) b(s) y(s) ds- \sin(\omega t) \int_0^t \cos(\omega s) b(s) y(s) ds$$

taking the absolute value $|y(t)| \le K\int_0^t |b(s)||y(s)| ds.$  here i am not too sure but the gronwall inequality now should give $|y| < |y(0)|exp(\int_0^t |b(s)|ds$
which is bounded above by $$|y(t)| \le |y(0)|exp\left(\int_0^\infty |b(t)|dt\right).$$

Comment: But this only shows any solution is at most a constant away from the $\sin(\omega t)$ rather than proves the proposition.

Comment: @Hans, you can add any transient solution and it will only change the $y(0)$ and at most add another constant which will take care of the phase. that is if you have a transient $A\sin(\omega t + \phi)$

Comment: I do not see how your comment resolves my objection that you have not shown the difference between the solution and $\sin(\omega t)$ vanishes at $\infty$ as the proposition requires. In other words, you have not proved the claim.

Comment: @Hans, you don't see that you can add a homogeneous solution $A\sin(\omega t + \phi)$ to the particular solution. bound the hgs solution by some constant. go back to the gronwall inequality.

Comment: Obviously you do not understand my objection. I agree with your first two sentences. If you read my first comment again, you will see my objection is that your statements do nothing to prove the proposition. All you have proved it that the solution is bounded, far short of the desired assertion. If you really think you have a complete proof, why don't you write the details out and carry the proof to the very end and conclude desired result instead of stopping in the middle?