# Question about solutions of $x''+(1+r(t))x=0$ when $\int_1^\infty |r(t)| dx <\infty$ .

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $x''+(1+r(t))x=0$ where $r(t)$ is continous and $\int_1^\infty |r(t)| dx <\infty$  show that the equation has solutions $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ such that $$\lim_{t\to\infty} [(\phi_1(t)-e^{it})=0$$ and $$\lim_{t\to\infty} [(\phi_1'(t)-ie^{it})=0$$
and $$\lim_{t\to\infty} [(\phi_2(t)-e^{-it})=0$$ and $$\lim_{t\to\infty} [(\phi_2'(t)+ie^{-it})=0$$

I don't know how to start to solve. I need some hint.

thanks.

Comment: Do you have any other conditions on $r$?

Comment: assume f is continous

Comment: aren't there derivatives somewhere?

Comment: @mookid: i corrected it

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033783/why-solutions-of-yw2bty-0-behave-like-solutions-of-yw2y-0-at-in?rq=1